# python schedule running every 5 minutes adds few seconds delay

Tags: python

I am running the below code as an example where the function gets data and cleans it and shows the result every five minutes.

```
import schedule
import time

def job():
    print("I'm working...")

schedule.every(5).minutes.do(job)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

The problem I have now is when the function runs, it takes a few seconds to do everything. For example, if the code runs at 9:00 am, it takes 2-5 seconds to complete the task. Due to this, the next time code runs at 9:05:05 seconds.

Is there a solution that can help me run the function every 5 minutes even after taking some time to complete the tasks in the function? I want the function to run exactly at 9:00 am, 9:05 am, and 9:10 am respectively.

Answer (score 2):

Run another thread as mentioned in schedule docs: https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

*Schedule does not account for the time it takes for the job function to execute. To guarantee a stable execution schedule you need to move long-running jobs off the main-thread (where the scheduler runs). See Parallel execution for a sample implementation.*

and once again I copy from documentation:

```
import threading
import time
import schedule

def job():
    print("I'm running on thread %s" % threading.current_thread())

def run_threaded(job_func):
    job_thread = threading.Thread(target=job_func)
    job_thread.start()

schedule.every(10).seconds.do(run_threaded, job)
schedule.every(10).seconds.do(run_threaded, job)
schedule.every(10).seconds.do(run_threaded, job)
schedule.every(10).seconds.do(run_threaded, job)
schedule.every(10).seconds.do(run_threaded, job)


while 1:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```